# Determining Mean Path Length

Tags: performance-tuning, distributions, geometry, trigonometry, pathfinding

I'm interested in working out the average path length in a square. Assume at a single point within the square, photons are released in every direction. I'm interested in determining the average path length for a photon to hit one edge of the square, here defined by the line $y=0$.

I have a solution that works, but it is unacceptably slow.

```
(* Say I have a square of length L *) 
l = 10;

(* number of photons to model*) 
n = 50;

(* emission point *) 
point = {RandomReal[{0, l}], RandomReal[{0, l}]};

(* angles of emission, isotropic*) 
pointsoncricle = 
  Table[point + {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &[N[2 \[Pi] k/n]], {k, 0, n - 1}];
circlepoints = Point[#] & /@ pointsoncricle ;

(* photon paths *) 
photonpath = HalfLine[{point, #}] & /@ pointsoncricle;

(* our acceptance aperture *) 
acceptance = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, l}}];

(* determine intersections with photon path and acceptance aperture *) \

intersections = RegionIntersection[{acceptance, #}] & /@ photonpath;
intersections = Select[intersections, # =!= EmptyRegion[2] &];

(* determine lengths *) 
pathlengths = 
  ArcLength[Line[{intersections[[#, 1, 1]], point}]] & /@ 
   Range[Length[intersections]];

(* plot everything *) 
Graphics[{{Pink, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {l, l}]}, acceptance, 
  Point[point], {Red, PointSize[0.02], intersections}, photonpath}]

(* see distribution *) 
Histogram[pathlengths, n/10]
Mean[pathlengths]
```

e.g., n=50, and n=500

[image]
[image]

But, to get a reasonable path length, I need to in excess of $n=1000$ paths,

[image]

Is there a computational more efficient way or potentially an analytical method to do determine the path length? Maybe just using some sort of distribution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: As pointed out by @DanielHuber in the comments, my original approach was assuming uniform distribution of the target points along the line instead of uniform distribution of the angles. Here's a corrected version: (the old answer is below)

### Updated answer

We can solve this analytically by integrating:

```
func[x_, y_] = Assuming[0 < x < 1 && 0 < y < 1,
  Integrate[
     Sqrt[x^2 + (ey - y)^2] D[ArcTan[x, ey - y], ey], {ey, 0, 1}]/
    Integrate[D[ArcTan[x, ey - y], ey], {ey, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify
  ]
(* (x Log[((1 + Sqrt[x^2 + (-1 + y)^2] - y) (y + Sqrt[
     x^2 + y^2])^2)/(
  x^2 (-1 + Sqrt[x^2 + (-1 + y)^2] + y))])/(2 (ArcTan[(1 - y)/x] + 
   ArcTan[y/x])) *)
```

[image]

The integral we are computing is essentially:

$\langle d\rangle=\frac{\int_{\theta_\mathrm{min}}^{\theta_\mathrm{max}}d(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{\int_{\theta_\mathrm{min}}^{\theta_\mathrm{max}}1\,\mathrm{d}\theta}
=\frac{\int_0^1d(y)\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}y}\,\mathrm{d}y}{\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}y}\,\mathrm{d}y}$

While the integration itself takes a while, evaluation at a single point will be extremely quick:

```
func[0.5, 0.5] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0000495, 0.5611} *)
```

We can even get exact results:

```
func[1/2, 1/2] // FullSimplify
(* ArcCosh[17]/(2 π) *)
```

### Old answer

This can be done fully analytically for an arbitrary point:

```
edge = Line@{{0, 0}, {0, 1}};
func[x_, y_] = Assuming[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1,
  Integrate[
     EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {ex, ey}], {ex, ey} ∈ edge]/
    RegionMeasure@edge // FullSimplify
  ]
(* 1/2 (Sqrt[x^2 + (-1 + y)^2] - Sqrt[x^2 + (-1 + y)^2] y + 
   y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + 
   x^2 (Log[1 + Sqrt[x^2 + (-1 + y)^2] - y] - 
      Log[-y + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]])) *)
```

[image]

While the integration itself takes a while, evaluation at a single point will be extremely quick:

```
func[0.5, 0.5] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0000299, 0.573897} *)
```

We can even get exact results:

```
func[1/2, 1/2] // FullSimplify
(* 1/4 (Sqrt[2] + ArcSinh[1]) *)
```

Comment: You integrate along the target line. This means the intersections of the photons are equally distributed on the target line. However, if the photons are emitted equally distributed over the angle, then they will hit the target line with an uneven distribution. Therefore, one need to integrate over the angle, not the target line. If needed I may show how this is done.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for catching that! I was so preoccupied with making the integration readable, that I didn't stop to consider whether it was actually correct :) - should be corrected now